# Python - Subprocess Module in a for loop

Tags: python, module, subprocess

I am new fairly new to Python and learning about the subprocess module.

I am trying to make a script to open multiple programs, but using a for loop. However, this is not working for me:

```
prog1 = ([r"C:\Program Files\example.exe"])
prog2 = ([r"C:\Program Files\example.exe"])

programs = [prog1, prog2]

for items in programs:
    time.sleep(1.5)
    subprocess.Popen([items])
```

I have done this using the webbrowswer module and this is working fine:

```
link1 = "https:example1.co.uk"
link2 = "https:example2.co.uk"
link3 = "https:example3.co.uk"
    
sites = [link1, link2, link3]
         
print("Launching Web Browser..")
        
for items in sites:
    time.sleep(1.5)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(items)
```

Can anybody advise if this can be done?

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.Popen(items)`? I'm not sure why you're wrapping `items` in another list when it's already a list.

Comment: @Kemp thank you - i have removed the [ ] from this and now is working fine. Something i will be keeping an eye on next time to prevent the same mistake :)